# Dynamic Properties Menu in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm trying to create a dynamic GUI menu in Godot 4.1.1, where when an object is selected it's properties can be seen in the GUI. So far, I have this working for un-editable fields - however there are also properties that will need to be edited.

`_on_grouped` is called whenever a node is added to a group and if it's "selected" then it's internal properties are generated for GUI controls and added.

```
@onready var properties_grid_container = $Properties/MarginContainer/VBoxContainer/ScrollContainer/GridContainer

func _add_property(name: String, value: String):
    var label = Label.new()
    label.text = name
    label.size_flags_horizontal = Control.SIZE_EXPAND_FILL

    var value_label = Label.new()
    value_label.text = value

    properties_grid_container.add_child(label)
    properties_grid_container.add_child(value_label)

func _on_grouped(group: String, node: Node):
    if group == "selected":
        properties_open = true

        # Remove all children from properties_grid_container
        for child in properties_grid_container.get_children():
            properties_grid_container.remove_child(child)
            child.queue_free()

        if node.parent_object is TypeOne:
            var my_object = node.parent_object

            # Add agent_id to properties
            _add_property("ID", str(my_object.custom_id))

        if node.parent_object is TypeTwo:

            var my_object = node.parent_object

            # Add agent_id to properties
            _add_property("Property Two", str(my_object.custom_property_two))
```

This all works fine (note this is a minimal example, each type has it's own method to extract the properties). However I'm now stuck on how I could extend this to editable properties.

I've got a start of a method like this:

```
func _add_editable_property(name: String, initial_value: String):
    var label = Label.new()
    label.text = name
    label.size_flags_horizontal = Control.SIZE_EXPAND_FILL

    var value_label = LineEdit.new()
    value_label.text = initial_value

    properties_grid_container.add_child(label)
    properties_grid_container.add_child(value_label)

    # Add a signal to the LineEdit to update the property
    #value_label.connect("text_changed", self._on_property_changed, [name, value_label])
```

However, I cannot think of a way to connect when the text is changed (or submitted) back to the original object. I would prefer to have this done automatically per field, rather than have a separate "save changes" button.

Does anyone have any ideas as to any approaches that could make this work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the function `_add_editable_property` to receive a callback function.

```
func _add_editable_property(name: String, initial_value: String, callback: Callable):
    var label = Label.new()
    label.text = name
    label.size_flags_horizontal = Control.SIZE_EXPAND_FILL

    var value_label = LineEdit.new()
    value_label.text = initial_value

    properties_grid_container.add_child(label)
    properties_grid_container.add_child(value_label)

    # You can use Godot 4 syntax here for connecting signals
    value_label.text_changed.connect(callback)
```

Then, in the _on_grouped function, you call _add_editable_property like this:

```
        if node.parent_object is TypeThree:
            var my_object = node.parent_object
            _add_property(
                 "Property Three", 
                 str(my_object.custom_property_three), 
                 func(new_value):
                      my_object.custom_property_three = new_value
            )
```

(I don't have the Godot editor on this machine right now, so I'm not confident about the formatting, but the syntax should be like this)

Comment: Ooh, using a lambda function as the callback. That's certainly something that didn't come to mind. I'll give it a test and mark as an answer if all ok!